# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count' - discord.py

Tags: python, discord

It's an update of my previous question ([AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count' discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65582318/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-count-discord-py?noredirect=1#comment115951626_65582318))

The problem is that Unicode emojis make the `emoji_count =  ...` line create an error. That's because Unicode emojis return `None` or `NoneType`, so `emoji = emoji` return `None` too, so the whole function creates an error.

The code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
msg = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
emoji = payload.emoji
author = payload.member
emoji_count = discord.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji=emoji).count
if payload.channel_id == channel_play:
    if author in buffer.members:
        if int(emoji_count) > 1:
            ...
            ...
            await msg.remove_reaction(emoji, author)
```

The error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\plays\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", 
line 312, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\plays\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Python\bot2.py", line 125, in on_raw_reaction_add
emoji_count = discord.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji = emoji).count
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
```

How can I solve that problem, so both custom and Unicode emojis will work properly? What should be written in the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if emoji.is_custom_emoji():
        emoji_count = discord.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji=emoji).count
    else:
        emoji_count = discord.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji = emoji.name).count
```